# SQL Server equal comparison between int and string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking at the return value for `year()` on SQL Server and it seems to be an int.

Then why does the following statement return 'equal'?

Why does the comparison operator consider int `2002` and string `'2002'` equal? Should it?

```
select 
    case 
        when year('2002-01-14 00:00:00.000') = '2002' then 'equal' 
        else 'not equal' 
    end
```

[Microsoft's Year Doc.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx)

Comment: Yes, sql server is doing an implict cast changing '2002' to a int.  it always attempts to cast the 2nd data type to the first one.

Comment: Whether something should or shouldn't happen doesn't matter.  What matter is that you know what does happen and code accordingly.

Comment: Good question, and nice answer from @xQbert.  There are some very good arguments against using [implicit casts](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/implicit-conversions-that-cause-index-scans/).  As a general rule, I try to avoid them in my dbs.

Comment: @destination-data nice article supporting avoiding implicit casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because SQL server is implicitly casting '2002' to the data type of of the first value in the equality check. (int) in this case